# Sorting through numbered files for program execution

Tags: bash

I have many files with the same format: mubunching-100302.0003.001_1c, mubunching-100302.0005.001_1c ...

I would like to feed a program many of these files that have a minimum value, e.g. only files with index *.0005.* and greater:

python Code.py mubunching-100302.0005.001_1c mubunching-100302.0008.001_1c ...

I am fairly new to bash and am not sure where to begin.  Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find` and `awk` to get the list of desired filenames:

```
find . -type f -name "mubunching*" | awk -F'[.]' '$(NF-1)>=5'
```

In order to pass the list to your program, use process substitution:

```
python Code.py $(find . -type f -name "mubunching*" | awk -F'[.]' '$(NF-1)>=5')
```

Comment: I think using `xargs` is a better solution because you will not run into argument length problems if there are a large number of files.

Comment: @larsks Define _large_.  It'd be good to provide a statistical figure.

Comment: "Large" varies from operating system to operating system, but if your command line length exceeds this value you'll get an "argument list too long" error.  If you're not familiar with this aspect of unix-like operating systems, [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/) has a good discussion of the situation, including how to find the limit for your OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of all files matching your criteria like this:

```
ls | awk -F. '$2 >= 5 {print}'
```

This has `awk` compare the 2nd `.` delimited field against `5`, and only print out names for which this is true.  If you want to then process these files with you Python script:

```
    ls | awk -F. '$2 >= 5 {print}' | xargs python Code.py
```

For example, given a directory containing:

```
$ ls
mubunching-100302.0002.001_1c  mubunching-100302.0005.001_1c
mubunching-100302.0003.001_1c  mubunching-100302.0008.001_1c
```

This first command above will produce:

```
$ ls | awk -F. '$2 >= 5 {print}'
mubunching-100302.0005.001_1c
mubunching-100302.0008.001_1c
```

Comment: I think you are missing the '[.]' ?  Will not work unless I use this.

Comment: No, '-F.' works.  Try `echo one.two.three | awk -F. '{print $3}'`

Comment: Parsing `ls` for simple filename output is just fine, especially when you have a namespace that you know a priori does not contain things like whitespace in filenames.  If you do have things that would cause problems, `find ... -print` is going to produce the same problems.  For example, consider piping `find -print` to `awk` when filenames contain newlines.  In this case, a solution using `find ... -print0` is going to be more robust, but also somewhat more complicated to implement.

Comment: @larsks The command _as-is_ would not even work.  It wasn't `-F'.'` that didn't work for the OP, it was `ls`.  It's obvious that you fail to understand that.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.  If you could update your answer with an example demonstrating the failure, that would be awesome!  I tested this locally with an admittedly small set of files and it appears to work correctly, although I did make some assumptions about the contents of the directory in which the command is run.

Comment: @larsks No, I don't feel the need to.